# Log in to Drupal site via C# application

Tags: c#, drupal

I want to log in to my Drupal site via a C# application and have been using OAuth and Services with no success. Is there a way to log in with a session from C#? I need to do this to access my private files on my Drupal site.

I tried to use the code below from a user here on stackoverflow with now success. I get 403 when using the code.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    if (request is HttpWebRequest)
    {
        (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
    }
    return request;
}
}

var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.BaseAddress = @"https://www.mysite.com/";
var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
loginData.Add("login", user);
loginData.Add("password", password);
client.UploadValues("login.php", "POST", loginData); // ERROR HERE

//Now you are logged in and can request pages    
string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no login.php in drupal. I think you need to check these examples: (RPC / Services 3)

https://drupal.org/node/308629

http://www.technogumbo.com/2012/05/Drupal-7-Services-3-REST-Server-C-Sharp-Example/